# Long listing format ls command [special character file data]

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ls

When using the `ls -l` command files that are not `Character special file (c)` or `Block special file (b)` before the last modification date they have just one number; the file size. Those 2, have 2 number separated by a comma. I've been looking for info on those, but could not find what they mean. What do these 2 numbers mean?

Example:

```
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   root      1,   7 abr  3  2020 full

brw-rw----  1 root   disk      7,  11 abr  3  2020 loop11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When data is read from, or written to, a device file, the request is handled by the driver for that device. Each device file has an associated number which identifies the driver to use. What those numbers are is *major number* -comma- *minor number* for the driver. The major number is a larger, more generic category (e.g. hard disks, input/output devices etc...) while the minor number is more specific (i.e. tells what bus the device is connected to). The minor number is used only by the driver specified by the major number; other parts of the kernel don’t use it, and merely pass it along to the driver.